# How to demonstrate that there are just 14 types of Bravais lattice?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

Is it possible to demonstrate that there are just 14 types of Bravais lattice without the knowledge of group theory?

Comment: The number of [Bravais lattices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice) depends on the dimension. You are apparently referring to the dimension $3$.

Comment: @Trimok question edited. I've read that Bravais originally proved that there are only 14 types of Bravais lattice in 3D with group theory, could it be done with basic math?

Comment: No, I don't think so, if you read the Wikipedia page about [Bravais lattice in 3 dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice#Bravais_lattices_in_3_dimensions), it makes reference to [Lattice systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_system) and [Point groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_group)